# Reverse the seomatic title and site name for a specific template

Tags: plugin-seomatic

Let's say my seomatic `Site SEO Name` = `My Site` and my `Site SEO Title` = `A Wonderful Website`

With the default values for seomatic's `Site SEO Name Placement` and `Site SEO Name Separator`, this will output the following title:

`<title>A Wonderful Website | My Site</title>`

This makes sense for the majority of pages on my site, where by setting a custom title for the page I'll get something like `About Us | My Site`

But on the homepage, I actually want to swap the order of these, so that the title becomes:

`<title>My Site | A Wonderful Website</title>`

This seems like a fairly common thing to do, but I can't seem to find a way to trick seomatic into allowing this without setting `Site SEO Name Placement` to `None` (which I don't want to do because the default value works well on all other pages).

Even trying to manually set the entire title won't work, because it will insist on adding the `Site SEO Name` to the end:

`{% set seomaticMeta = seomaticMeta | merge({ seoTitle: 'My Site | A Wonderful Website' }) %}`

Any way around this?

Answer (score 5):

The following works (but is undocumented):

`{% set seomaticSiteMeta = seomaticSiteMeta | merge({'siteSeoTitlePlacement': 'before'}) %}`